# How to implement this jquery easy ui comobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-easyui

I want to add [Jquery easy ui](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php%3Fplugin%3DComboBox) comobox in my blog but iam not able to find this script files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

The above are the script files iam unable to find any way to implement any example would help me. thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Basic ComboBox - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/default/easyui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/icon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../demo.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Basic ComboBox</h2>
        <p>Type in ComboBox to try auto complete.</p>
        <div style="margin:20px 0"></div>
        <div class="easyui-panel" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;padding:30px 60px;">
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <label class="label-top">State:</label>
                <select class="easyui-combobox" name="state" style="width:100%;height:26px;">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH" selected>Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Unable to find" ? Phisically ? http://www.jeasyui.com/download/index.php

Answer (score 0):

you can make you own copies of these .css on your local machines. Copy them from the following links:

http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css
http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css
http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css
http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css